# Convert time string to seconds

Tags: ruby, time

I have a Ruby command line tool that accepts `--duration` option with a number of seconds, for example `--duration 300`. I want to extend this option to accept simple time strings like:

- `--duration 30s` -> thirty seconds
- `--duration 45m` -> forty-five minutes -> 2700 seconds
- `--duration 5h` -> five hours -> 18000 seconds
- `--duration 2d` -> two days -> 172800 seconds
- `--duration 3M` -> three months -> ninety days -> 7776000 seconds

Seconds (`s`), minutes (`m`), hours (`h`), days (`d`), months (`M`) are the only inputs I plan to accept. Accepting formats like `2d6h` is not required.

The seconds is not a time object or anything in the tool, it is an integer that is sent in a POST request, like `?duration=18000`.

Comment: While it might not be an exact fit, [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) is extremely useful for this sort of processing.

Answer (score 4):

While there might be a time library that does this better, this should do the trick:

```
time_multipliers = {
  's' => 1,
  'm' => 60,
  'h' => 60 * 60,
  'd' => 60 * 60 * 24,
  'M' => 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
}

duration = '30m' #whatever
duration, unit = duration.match(/(\d+)([smhdM])/).captures
duration_in_secs = duration.to_i * time_multipliers[unit]
```

Worth mentioning though: months are weird. A month isn't really 30 days, so you either want to not offer that confusing option, or be *really* clear that you don't really mean month, and that you really just mean 30 days.

Comment: ...and then there's the changing of the clocks twice annually in some parts of the world.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Basically, time is a mess. At least the length of minutes, hours, and days are defined though.

Comment: Defined, but not constant and as a result slowly losing accuracy. Darn that entropy.

Comment: I never give the option for month. Because of the range of possible days in a month, and the code mess and user confusion that could occur, it's easier to stick with days or weeks as the largest unit. The user enters "1M" not thinking about whether it's February with a leap year.

Comment: Appreciate all the month warnings, anticipating these I meant to note in the question for this purpose one month = thirty days. This tool creates a monitoring maintenance period and if someone is setting the maintenance for 3 months, they are saying "about three months should be fine" not "in exactly 91 days this needs to end". But yes I 100% agree with the idea that people should be aware that one month != thirty days.

Comment: @theTinMan: You'd think that there's something poetic about time, but for a programmer, it's really just irritating.

Comment: Darn tootin'. And explaining to kids these days about the differences between Time and DateTime and where they come from and why we'd use one over the other, even with the extensions to Time to extend the handled range it's still good to understand. And then their eyes glaze over.